# How can I recursively convert map<string, string> to map<string, object>

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a use case in which I want to convert string to its appropriate Java primitive type.

`Map<String,String>`. To `Map<String,Object>`

```
{
“Payload”: {“a”:”12”,”b”:”C”}
}
```

to

```
{
“Payload”: {“a”:12,”b”:”C”}
}
```

I thought of using `parseInt`, `parseBoolean` and others to try catch but not sure about the complete code.

Comment: And what's the advantage then? Then you either declare every variable refering to a value as `Object` or need to check the type again.

Comment: You can use a for-loop to go over the entries or the keys of the map and decide for each how to convert.

Comment: @mayamar how would we decide the data type to which I need to convert.  Is it like try to convert if exception is there and try other

Comment: @user16320675 can you pls put a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> target = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> source = Map.of("a", "12", "b", "C");
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter = source.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next();
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String val = entry.getValue();
            Object obj;
            try {
                obj = Long.valueOf(val);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException x0) {
                try {
                    obj = Double.valueOf(val);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException x1) {
                    if (val.length() == 1) {
                        char c = val.charAt(0);
                        if (Character.isDefined(c)) {
                            obj = Character.valueOf(c);
                        }
                        else {
                            obj = null;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
                            obj = Boolean.TRUE;
                        }
                        else if ("false".equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
                            obj = Boolean.FALSE;
                        }
                        else {
                            obj = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (obj != null) {
                target.put(key, obj);
            }
        }
        target.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("%s = %s [%s]%n",
                                                             entry.getKey(),
                                                             entry.getValue(),
                                                             entry.getValue().getClass()));
    }
}
```

Running above code produces following output:

```
a = 12.0 [class java.lang.Long]
b = C [class java.lang.Character]
```

Comment: Worth pointing out to OP this is iterative and not recursive, however it really makes no sense to use recursion for this problem.